# How to change package name of a project from 2 subdirectories to 3. Eg: "com.package" to "com.package.name"

Tags: android

As summarised from the title, I am trying to change the package name to include one more subdirectory.

I went through the regular process of deselecting `Compact Middle Packages` and attempting to refactor.

**What I have: "com.example"**

**What I want: "com.something.else"**

Here are some things I have tried that have not worked.

1. I tried to rename **"example"** to **"something.else"** but the resulting package name was **"com.else"** instead of **"com.something.else"** (This was dumb but I tried it anyway)
2. Since the **"."** in a package name simply denotes a sub-package, I renamed ***example*** and called it ***something***, after which I created a new package within **"something"** and called that **"else"**, within which I moved all my code.

Now this gave the illusion of the package name I wanted since I actually had **"com.something.else"** but the problem here is, that new package I added obviously will not affect the `androidTest` and `test` packages... 
I also went into my gradle to change the `applicationId` to match my new package... But that didnt work either... Its throwing build errors now..

Error log.

> Process 'command '/Home/directory/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/aidl'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Don't know what is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

android studio bugged with this scenario. any way you use to rename whole app package will need to change something by hands.

And do not forget to invalidate caches in main menu

Comment: I did try `invalidate caches and restart` but i kept getting the same error message when I tried to build.
Also, besides the application id, is there something else I need to change?